# How to map array of Enum associated values into array of AnyObject Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am decoding an array of json activities by using an enum that switches over their "type" property (like, comment, follow) and decodes accordingly.

However I am having trouble with getting the associated values because it decodes as **AppName.NotificationEnum.like(AppName.LikeActivity(*id:type:username:createdAt:*)**

How can I get each value and append it to notifications: AnyObject ?

Normally I would append a decoded array of objects into an array of matching type but since each of my notification objects will have different properties (*I want to avoid optionals) they need to be handled based on their *type*.*

After adding these values to my AnyObject array I will switch over them and assign the data it to its specific notification view...

THANK YOU

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var notifications: [AnyObject]()

   func loadCurrentUserProfileData() {
       //API CODE

      switch response {
          case .success(let profileData):
                print("Notifications:", profileData.notifications) // see output below..
               self.notifications.append(contentsOf: profileData.notifications)
          case .failure(let error):
              // handle erros
      }           
}
```

Array of Enum values I need to extract and append to **@Published var notifications: [AnyObject] = []**

```
[AppName.NotificationsEnum.like(AppName.LikeActivity(id: "61dc9d0715", type: "like", username: "testuser", createdAt: 2022-01-10 20:45:38 +0000)), 
AppName.NotificationsEnum.like(AppName.LikeActivity(id: "61dc9cd072f", type: "like", username: "testuser", createdAt: 2022-01-10 20:45:38 +0000)),
 AppName.NotificationsEnum.like(AppName.LikeActivity(id: "61dc9d0735", type: "like", username: "testuser", createdAt: 2022-01-10 20:45:38 +0000)) ]
```

```
enum NotificationsEnum: Decodable {
    
    case like(LikeActivity)
    case comment(CommentActivity)
    case collect(FollowActivity)
        
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
    }
    
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
    let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case "like":
            self = try .like(LikeActivity(from: decoder))
        case "comment":
            self = try .comment(CommentActivity(from: decoder))
         case "follow":
            self = try .follow(FollowActivity(from: decoder))
        default:
             throw DecodingError.wrongJSON
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the notifications are all of the type `NotificationsEnum`, it's unclear why you want to use `[AnyObject]` instead of `[NotificationsEnum]`. Can you clarify that?

Comment: I need to use the properties that are on LikeActivity, CommentActivity, & FollowActivity; such as id: userId: likeId: createdAt: type: for each kind of activity. NotificationsEnum is only being used to decode each type of these models depending on the "type" property.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but typically you would get those by switching over the enum cases such as `switch item { case .like(let activity): ... }` See: https://www.objc.io/blog/2018/09/04/switching-with-associated-values/

Comment: Yea I've been having a hard time figuring this out today because I'm used to decoding objects that all have the same properties...

Comment: Yes, I can see you doing that in the `init(from decoder: Decoder)`. But, that doesn't seem to explain why you would want to store them in `[AnyObject]` (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: I wanted to do a generic type of array where I can add any type of activity object, then switch its type (like, comment, follow) so that I can route it to its specific view cell inside of a for each. Each activity view accepts a certain type of activity in my case...

Comment: This still sounds like you should be using `[NotificationsEnum]` and using case binding to the associated values as I linked to before. I can write up an answer if you're unclear of what this would look like, but I won't if there's a reason you're opposed to this approach and are looking for a different direction.

Comment: ok I'll look into that, thank you!

Comment: agree with @jnpdx about the approach.  I always used to forget this and put together a blog entry for it, mainly for my benefit.  It covers a very similar scenario, so may be of help: https://www.darrengillman.com/index.php/2019/11/22/decoding-heterogenous-json-with-swift-and-decodable/